# Do 2 sets exist that are neither open nor closed, but their union is both open and closed.

Tags: general-topology

I'm under the impression that only 2 clopen sets exist ${\rm I\!R}$ and $\emptyset$?

So does there exist 2 sets neither open or closed that form one of these clopen sets?

Comment: Take any set that is neither open nor closed, and its complement.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ and $\emptyset$ are the only open-and-closed sets in the usual topology on $\Bbb R. $ This is because  it is a connected space.   In general if $A$ is  a subset of a space $S$, and $A$ is neither open nor closed,  let $B=S\setminus A.$ Then $B$ is not open or closed. But $A\cup B=S$, which  is open and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the set of rational numbers and the set of irrational numbers are neither open nor closed but the union is the set of real numbers which is both open and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Consider:
$$
A = (-\infty, 3) \cup [4, 7]
$$
and
$$
B = [3, 4) \cup (7, \infty)
$$